# Client Side Validation Not working for custom Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

Hi 
I have a custom Attribute

```
 public class NameAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
 {
     public NameAttribute() : base("abc*") { }
 }
```

This works on the serverside but not in the client side but this

```
[RegularExpressionAttribute("abc*",ErrorMessage="asdasd")]
public String LastName { get; set; }
```

works on both. I read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) but it does'nt help.

I would really appreciate your assistance.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to register a `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` associated to this custom attribute in `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
        typeof(NameAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter)
    );
}
```

You might also checkout the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx).

And here's the full example I used to test this.

Model:

```
public class NameAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public NameAttribute() : base("abc*") { }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    [Name(ErrorMessage = "asdasd")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js") %>"></script>

<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.LastName) %>
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.LastName) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LastName) %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

Plus the `Application_Start` registration I showed earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I wish I could give you more than just 1 point